# Is there a standard power adaptor to use on airplanes?

Tags: air-travel, gear, power, electronic-items

For international flights of 12-15+ hours, do the planes usually have AC power available in Economy? If not, is there a standard "airplane power adaptor" that can convert the DC into AC to power a laptop or other electronic item? Is this the same type of adaptor that you can use in cars, or is it a different plug type on an airplane?

Comment: I've had normal power outlets on AA 737s on domestic US flights, and also seen DC power adaptors, likely the EmPower mentioned below, but I'm mainly concerned with long-haul flights with this question.

Comment: Worth noting that many PEDs nowadays are perfectly capable of going for 12-15+ hours on a full battery charge.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

When power outlets were first installed on airliners, they used a special adapter called [EmPower](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EmPower_(aircraft_power_adapter)), which looked like this:

[image]

The airlines obviously thought that frequent flyers would be happy to buy a new kind of adapter for all their gizmos. This turned out not to be entirely true... nobody wanted to buy these new stupid adapters, and the airlines eventually realized that it wasn't going to work.

So they are now installing "normal" power outlets... often special receptacles with all kinds of holes that can handle just about any kind of plug, US, European, or British. If they already installed the EmPower thing, they're regretting it and replacing it with standard receptacles as fast as they can.

There is no standard rule to decide if your flight is going to have power, except for the following vague rules of thumb:

- The higher your class of service (First vs. Coach) the more likely you are to have power
- The longer the flight, the more likely you are to have power

The canonical way to find out is by finding out the exact aircraft you'll be flying on, and looking it up on [SeatGuru](http://seatguru.com) to see where the power outlets are and whether they are EmPower or AC. Most airline websites will also have details on where power is available.

Comment: I figured SeatGuru on a case-by-case basis was likely the answer, but didn't know if there were any other standards. Thanks!

Comment: interesting that the takes-my-normal-plug-and-probably-everyone's socket in the picture I found has an EmPower logo on it. Seems like they changed their ways too.

Comment: I just took the flight that I was asking this question for, a Cathay Pacific 777-300 from ORD-HKG and while SeatGuru said it had "EmPower" outlets, it had the same outlet as the Air Canada one that @KateGregory mentions. I'm glad I didn't buy an adaptor.

Answer (score 11):

Air Canada has power in economy. It is a standard North American plug. There was a brief time when in-air power required a special airline-only adapter, similar to the way headphones had that strange two-prong plug. But I think these days if there's power it will be a "normal" plug for that airline. The only adapter you are likely to need is one you would use anyway in the country you're heading to.

After reading Joel's answer I realized that the plug is a little more complicated than a North American plug (though my stuff fits in it fine) and found this picture:

[image]

Perhaps most European devices could also use this plug.

Comment: Right, from the photo, it looks like a dual US/Europe socket.

Comment: Looks to me like it will take australian plugs too.

Comment: I don't think this particular one will take Australian plugs.

Answer (score 4):

I haven't flown an airline offering power in economy, but Apple offers an [Apple MagSafe Airline Adapter](http://store.apple.com/us/product/MB441Z/A), so I guess that the answer to that part of your question is yes, otherwise apple is lying. 
[Seatguru.com](http://seatguru.com) offers insight which airline offers in flight power, but I could not find one that offers power in economy.

Comment: Apparently, it was designed to connect to the EmPower plugs described in the other answers but it's not available anymore so the answer now seems incorrect.

Answer (score 3):

I have seen power outlets offered in economy a few times.  Most recently on a UK to US flight with United.  Also, on some internal flights.  The sockets took US plugs and delivered something that my laptop power supply was happy with: probably 110V 60Hz.  Fortunately, most laptop and other portable device power supplies are quite tolerant these days.  If something bad came out of the socket then I hope that the power supply would lay down its life for the device it served.  I had a power block with me but power was so easily available for the whole trip that I never used it.

Comment: I've noticed a lot of economy seats that have recent in-seat entertainment monitors often have a USB port as well. It doesn't help much with a laptop, but good for charging a phone or anything else that can charge off of USB.